# Not getting the expected output in my c# program, Incorrect Format of Date is getting written in the file

Tags: c#

I've written code that should not accept incorrect format of the date. Mine displays invalid choice but stores the incorrect format of the date in the text file. If the date is in incorrect format, it should not be stored in the text file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
class FunWithScheduling
{
    public void AddView()
    {
        FileStream s = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name of the Person To Be Met:");
        string Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime date;

        if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Time Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Time = Console.ReadLine();
        string line = Name + "                                "+ Date +"             " + Time;
        w.WriteLine(line);
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
        s.Close();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        FunWithScheduling a = new FunWithScheduling();
        a.AddView();
    }
}
```

This modified program doesn't work. While is never ending and the correct format of the date is not accepted nor saved in the text file.

I am not allowed to use the string builder.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
class FunWithScheduling
{
    public void AddView()
    {
        FileStream s = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name of the Person To Be Met:");
        string Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime date;
        if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid date format!");
            while(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date Entered, please format MM-dd-yyyy");
                Date = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Time Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Time = Console.ReadLine();
        string line = Name + "                                "+ Date +"             " + Time;
        w.WriteLine(line);
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
        s.Close();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        FunWithScheduling a = new FunWithScheduling();
        a.AddView();
    }
}
```

Comment: What should the output format look like?

Comment: What have you entered as test (the accepted one)?

Comment: The correct format of the date is month/date/year anything apart from this should not get stored in my text file. Only the correct format of the date should be stored in my text file.

Comment: Though my program displays invalid message if the user enters the incorrect format of the date but it still gets stored in my text file, which should not happen.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add:

```
return;
```

after :

```
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
```

Also better to move `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` initialization till after the condition check:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
class FunWithScheduling
{
     public void AddView()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name of the Person To Be Met:");
        string Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime date;
        if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
        {
               Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
               return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Time Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Time = Console.ReadLine();
        string line = Name + "                                "+ Date +"             " + Time;
        FileStream s = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
        w.WriteLine(line);
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
        s.Close();
      }
      static void Main()
      {
        FunWithScheduling a = new FunWithScheduling();
        a.AddView();
      }
}
```

Comment: returning at that point will hang the app. The stream won't close and the line's won't write properly. It would be a little more complicated than that.

Comment: A try/catch/finally might be a better approach. Or as my answer states, `else` with a `stringbuilder`

Comment: It hangs. Doesn't work. Even the correct format of the date is not accepted. Adel Khayata

Comment: I have tested my proposed code and it doesn't hang in both cases ( valid & invalid date ) and it will allow the correct format, Did you try my proposed code?

Comment: I too tried your code Adel. If i enter the date as 13/10/2013 it displays invalid choice if i enter 12/12/2013 it displays the same invalid message when the date format is correct.

Comment: I use visual studio 2008

Comment: For 13/10/2013, it is giving me : "Invalid Choice" !!

Comment: What about 12/12/2013 can you see the same invalid choice being displayed again.

Comment: 12/12/2013 is giving me "Invalid Choice", but 12-12-2013 is saving to the file.

Comment: Either way it's not getting stored

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an "else" statement to fix issue of "Date". And then use a [String Builder](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder) instead of `+` and build the string.

I've tried to help you here, but I haven't run it through a compiler.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
class FunWithScheduling
{
     public void AddView()
     {
        FileStream s = new FileStream("Scheduler.txt",FileMode.Append,FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Name of the Person To Be Met:");
        string Name = Console.ReadLine();
        builder.Append(Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Date = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime date;
        if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
        {
               Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
        } else {
            builder.Append(date.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Time Scheduled For the Meeting:");
        string Time = Console.ReadLine();
        builder.Append(Time);
        w.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        w.Flush();
        w.Close();
        s.Close();
      }
      static void Main()
      {
        FunWithScheduling a = new FunWithScheduling();
        a.AddView();
      }
}
```

You could also try a while statement similar to this in order to force the user to input the right date.

```
    while(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date)){
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date Entered, please format MM-dd-yyyy");
        Date = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Ruckus could also use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b2t77weh.aspx) method to format the output directly on the StremWriter. Ruckus, please consider using "using" to dispose the streams.

Comment: yeah, a using statement would be great, and the possibility of a `while` statement to force the user to input the appropriate date/time

Answer (score 0):

// Make Date as blank when entered date is invalid; it will not be stored in the text file.

```
if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",
   new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
    Date = "";
}
```

Comment: why is 12/12/2013 is displaying invalid choice when it is the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes, use a StringBuilder instead of just + with string, because when you do that, string will multiply the memory usage of both of the strings, which means you have 2 memory allocations for 2 separated strings, and 1 for the con-catted one, just a tip for future.

All you need to do is either do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(Name);

if(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date,"MM-dd-yyyy",new CultureInfo("en-US"),DateTimeStyles.None,out date))
    {
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");

    }
    else 
    {
        sb.Append(Date);
    }
```

and then when you write to the file itself just do

```
w.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options when the user enter the wrong date:

1. Close the stream and  exit out of the code.
2. Ask the user to re-enter the date by specifying the format.

To close the stream and exit out you must add below code after:

```
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");
w.Flush();
w.Close();
s.Close();
return;
```

And

To ask the user to re-enter, until he specifies the correct answer, add below code after:

```
Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice");

while(!DateTime.TryParseExact(Date, "MM-dd-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{    
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Date Entered, please format MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: The while is never ending and it doesn't seem to accept the correct format of the date.

Comment: I have tested my proposed code and it doesn't hangs. Have u tried adding this code exactly after the statement Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice"); inside the if block. try with any date example 08-15-2013 it will work